# Getting FlywayException: SP2-0310: unable to open file - when sqlpus @ is used with file path

Tags: java, oracle, sqlplus, flyway

I am using flyway pro with oracleSqlplus enabled. I created a folder structure to organize scripts based on objects. Trying to use @ (with path) in the flyway version scripts, which is not working.

folder structure,

`topFolder
    -folderA
        -AScript.sql
    -folderB
        -BScript.sql
    -folderCommon
        -AScript.sql
    -V1__ASCRIPT.sql
    -V2__BSCRIPT.sql
    -V3__ASCRIPT.sql`

Content of:
 
V1__ASCRIPT.sql
@AScript.sql -> Which correctly executes topFolder/folderA/Ascript.sql
V2__BScript.sql
@BScript.sql -> Which correctly executes topFolder/folderB/Bscript.sql
V3__ASCRIPT.sql
@topFolder/folderCommon/AScript.sql -> Which is throwing me below error,
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: SP2-0310: unable to open file "topFolder/folderCommon/AScript.sql"

I tried almost all possible combinations,
with absolute path, 
with "@../../topFolder/folderCommon/AScript.sql"
tried setting SQLPATH varible
with @@ 
which didnt work. 
Just giving the file name alone in @, works. But I want to specify the path, so that file names can be re-used and it is less error prone.

I expect the relative path should work with flyway + oraclesqlplus option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please open an issue in the Flyway issue tracker with your exact folder structure and Flyway configuration so we can discuss this further.

Comment: Thanks Axel, sure will do.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you start the path from the point where fly `flyway.locations=filesystem:`  ends is where your path begins.
Example:

```
flyway.locations=filesystem:/opt/app/sql
```

where you scripts are `/opt/app/sql/appadb/script.sql`

inside masterscript would be 
`@@appadb/script.sql`